# Remove screen brightness increased in A fragment to move in B fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a scenario where I need to increase the brightness of screen programmatically of one fragment and when user moves to another fragment then the effect should be removed.

I am using this piece of code to increase the brightness of fragment.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
mActivity.getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.screenBrightness = 1.0F;
mActivity.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

I am moving to another fragment and I want that screen in normal brightness, I am able to do that in activity but it was stuck in fragment.

Comment: Can you reset the brightness to lower value in `onPause` of the first fragment?

Comment: @AleksG If I am setting the the values in onPause then user is not able to change the brightness of screen from status bar, because we are setting that lower value, we don't have any broadcast that listen brightness change.

Comment: I need that code should disable, I don't want to set it to any lower value of brightness.

Comment: Well, generally changing the brightness from your app just because you want to is not a very good idea.  Brightness is something up to the user - and the user should control it. You'd need to somehow manage the interaction between your activity setting the brightness and the user changing it.

Comment: Off-topic, but as a user, if the app overrides my settings (including brightness), that app would get removed from my device _very_ quickly.

Comment: @AleksG is Paytm removed, this app is using the same, click next line of qr code scanner "Show Paytm code" , same i need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196051/discussion-between-nitesh-and-aleks-g).